# Python - Read remote CSV file with utf-8-sig encoding

Tags: python, csv, request, urllib

I need to read a remote CSV file that I've uploaded on my server. I tried the following way, the file is read as text but it's not reading all the rows, it's reading the data in a strange way, like splitting the strings. The file has semi colon delimiters and is encoded with `utf-8-sig`.

```
import csv
import pprint
import urllib


url = "http://myfakesite.com/mycsv.csv"
r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
csv_file = r.read().decode(encoding="utf-8-sig")
reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=";")
for row in reader:
    pprint(row["Choice"])
```

Is there any other way to read the file without having problems?

Answer (score 0):

What about using pandas?

```
import pandas
csv = pandas.read_csv('http://myfakesite.com/mycsv.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')
print(csv['Choice'].tolist())
```

Comment: I'd prefer sticking with the standard csv module because I've got a lot of code using that module and I would need to change all that code to use pandas